# Apply changes into 3 projects?

Tags: unity-game-engine, ipad, oculus

I have a project which is divided into Oculus Rift (windows), Oculus Go (android) and iPad(iOS). They are basically the same projects except for few script changes. Now if I want to add a model to the scene, I have to add it to three different projects which takes alot of time. Is there a way that I can just add it to one Project (maybe windows) and then this will be reflected in other projects as well? Is there a simpler solution?

Comment: Using compiler #if is probably the easier, as you only have one project. https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/PlatformDependentCompilation.html

Comment: @Jichael sorry the project is same but its divided into 3 different projects due to build reasons. If i have one project then to switch between builds takes 2 hours.

Comment: There is assets that makes worflow faster, such as https://assetstore.unity.com/detail/tools/utilities/turbo-switch-pro-60040 . Believe me, having a separate project for each platform will lead to way too much trouble (way way more than just waiting "2hours")

Comment: You could maybe rather have 3 different scenes, change you build settings accordingly and rather use prefabs for the models so it is updated in every scene. If switching takes 2 hours something else is wrong ;)

Comment: @derHugo Thanks i shall try to do that